# how to read hdf5 boolean enum created by h5py in C

Tags: c, scientific-computing, hdf5, h5py

I've created an array with 3 doubles and one boolen using `numpy` and written them to file using `h5py`:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

data = np.zeros(10, dtype=[("THETA",np.double),("PHI",np.double),("PSI",np. double),("FLAG",np.bool)])

with h5py.File("testout.h5") as f:
    f.create_dataset("data", data=data)
```

`h5py` creates an enum type for the boolean field:

```
HDF5 "testout.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   DATASET "data" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_COMPOUND {
         H5T_IEEE_F64LE "THETA";
         H5T_IEEE_F64LE "PHI";
         H5T_IEEE_F64LE "PSI";
         H5T_ENUM {
            H5T_STD_I8LE;
            "FALSE"            0;
            "TRUE"             1;
         } "FLAG";
      }
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 10 ) / ( 10 ) }
   }
}
}
```

now I need to read this file using C, and things get complicated:

```
typedef enum {
    false = 0;
    true
} bool;

typedef struct {
    double THETA, PHI, PSI;
    bool FLAG;
} pointing_t;
```

I do not understand how to define a type that has an enum:

```
hid_t memtype = H5Tcreate (H5T_COMPOUND, sizeof(pointing_t));
H5Tinsert (memtype, "THETA", HOFFSET (pointing_t, THETA),  H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE);
H5Tinsert (memtype, "PHI", HOFFSET (pointing_t, PHI),  H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE);
H5Tinsert (memtype, "PSI", HOFFSET (pointing_t, PSI),  H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE);
# this should be an ENUM!!
H5Tinsert (memtype, "FLAG", HOFFSET (pointing_t, FLAG),  H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE);
```

I pasted a complete "not working" example on gist that tries to read the hdf5 files created with the previous python snippet:

http://gist.github.com/3168909

anybody has suggestions?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, you need to create an enum type in hdf5:

```
#define CPTR(VAR,CONST) ((VAR)=(CONST),&(VAR))
hid_t boolenumtype = H5Tcreate(H5T_ENUM, sizeof(bool));
status = H5Tenum_insert(boolenumtype, "FALSE",   CPTR(val, FALSE ));
printf ("H5Tenum_insert (FALSE): %i\n", status);
status = H5Tenum_insert(boolenumtype, "TRUE",   CPTR(val, TRUE ));
printf ("H5Tenum_insert (TRUE): %i\n", status);
```

and then add it to the memtype:

```
H5Tinsert (memtype, "FLAG", HOFFSET (pointing_t, FLAG),  boolenumtype);
```

the example on github is now working.

Answer (score 4):

An easier way to deal with this issue is to use 1-byte unsigned chars to store boolean types. In h5py, you can store a boolean array by invoking the following

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

# Generate some boolean data

shape = (100, 100)
data = np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.bool)

# Save the boolean data as uchars

f = h5py.File('foo.h5')
dset = f.create_dataset('/bar', dtype='u1', shape=shape)
dset[:] = data[:]
```

In C/C++, you can read the uchars into a `bool*` array, and they will be interpreted correctly. This is because they are 1-byte, just like C/C++ boolean values, and anything with nonzero bits is interpreted in C/C++ as `true`.